# pandas fillna: How to fill only leading NaN from beginning of series until first value appears?

Tags: python, pandas

I have several `pd.Series` that usually start with some NaN values until the first real value appears. I want to pad these leading NaNs with 0, but not any NaNs that appear later in the series.

```
pd.Series([nan, nan, 4, 5, nan, 7])
```

should become

```
ps.Series([0, 0, 4, 5, nan, 7])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
s.loc[:s.first_valid_index()] = 0
```

Or [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with `isnull` and forward filling `NaN`s:

```
s = s.mask(s.ffill().isnull(), 0)
```

---

```
print (s)
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    4.0
3    5.0
4    NaN
5    7.0
dtype: float64
```

EDIT: For function per groups use:

```
def func(x):
    x['col1'] = x['col1'].mask(x['col1'].ffill().isnull(), 0)
    return x


df = df.groupby('col').apply(func)
```

Comment: The `loc` solution leads to incorrect output because a `loc[:x]` slice includes the `x` label. From the docs: "Note that contrary to usual python slices, **both** the start and the stop are included".

Comment: How do you do this when you want to ffill() or bfill() on a grouped subset of a dataframe? `groupby` object has no `mask`.. Say I have a multi index (Season x Team), and want to ffill only for each team, after grouping by Team?

Comment: @KingOtto - Answer was edited.